# Building in a where clause in a Timestamp field select

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp, where-clause, clause

I've read on here all the posts I can, but none of the suggested solutions work.
I have a Timestamp field that I'd like to use in a where clause...

My Syntax is..

```
    select (TO_CHAR(Strt_Dt, 'YYYYMMDD HH24 MI SS')) as Test,
Strt_Dt
     from
    Some_Table
    where
      Strt_Dt > between timestamp '2021-03-26 17:00:00' and timestamp '2021-03-26 17:10:00'
```

I get values OUTSIDE of that range, although all for the 26 of March...
what am I doing wrong?
(field Strt_Dt defined as Timestamp(6) on the DB).

Thank you!

Comment: TO_CHAR is an oracle function is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: I am using it in Teradata as well

Answer (score 1):

A Team member of mine assisted - it is because of TimeZone issues - we are in South Africa, so our installation of Teradata defaults to 00:00.
In my where clause I need to have an Extra  +00:00 at the end, otherwise it defaults to 02:00